# How to join Kafka KStream with Plain file cache on Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a log enrichment Kafka Stream job. The plan is to use the file cache on Azure Blob to enrich the log entry from the Kafka KStream. My understanding is that I have to load the cache file from Azure Blob to a KTable. Then I can join the KStream with the KTable.

As a newbie, there are two difficulties I've met, can anyone give me some hint?

1. Looks like Kafka Connect doesn't have lib to connect to Azure Blob. Do I have to write another separate job to always read from Azure and write back to KTable? Is there any quick way?
2. The cache got updated four to five times every day and the job need to detect the change of the cache file and reflect in the KTable. To detect if some of entries deleted from the cache file, does it mean I have to compare each entries between the KTable and the file timely? Any more efficient way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this. The first thing you need to realize it, that you need to put the data into a Kafka topic first if you want to read it into a `KTable`.

If there is no connector, you could write your own connector (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html). An alternative would be, to write a small application, that reads the data from Azure and uses a `KafkaProducer` to write into a topic.

For updating the `KTable`, you don't need to worry about this from a Kafka Streams perspective. If new data is written into the topic, the `KTable` will be updated automatically. If you write you own connector, this will also ensure, that update to the file will be propagated into the topic automatically. If you write your own application, you will need to make sure, that this application write the changes into the topic.